# Creating a multithreaded server using SocketServer framework in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
import shlex
import subprocess
import SocketServer

sess = []

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        global sess
        sess.append(self.request)
        ip,port = self.client_address
        print "#%d: client %s:%d"%(len(sess),ip,port)
        while True:
            cmd = self.request.recv(8192)
            out = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
            self.request.send(out)
        self.request.close()
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SocketServer.TCPServer): pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 4242
    svr = ThreadedTCPServer(("",port),TCPHandler)
    print ":%d"%port
    svr.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is much more simple than you think:

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SocketServer.TCPServer): pass
```

Than you just have to use your new `ThreadedTCPServer` instead of `TCPServer`.

For more information you can read [some doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#module-SocketServer).

However in your code you made some mistakes:

1. The `target` argument must be a `callable` object not an "already-called" object.
2. To handle many requests you need to build a Threads pool. If you only use one thread it does not make any difference if it is the main thread or a "child" thread.

Comment: Well, thanks. The example in docs is complicated for newbie like me. So, I used your idea and now my programme works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
import shlex
import subprocess
import SocketServer

sess = []

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        global sess
        sess.append(self.request)
        ip,port = self.client_address
        print "#%d: client %s:%d"%(len(sess),ip,port)
        while True:
            cmd = self.request.recv(8192)
            out = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
            self.request.send(out)
        self.request.close()
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SocketServer.TCPServer): pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 4242
    svr = ThreadedTCPServer(("",port),TCPHandler)
    print ":%d"%port
    svr.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This line `thread.start_new_thread(server.serve_forever(),())` should simply be `server.serve_forever()`.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't you loop the

```
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('',1520), service)
t = Thread(target=server.serve_forever())
t.start()
```

Just a guess..