# HTTPServer.shutdown returns but the socket is still open

Tags: python, sockets, httpserver

I have the following code that I use to run a local HTTP server on port 8000:

```
# Omitted imports and irrelevant things for brevity.

class ThreadedHTTPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class MyClass(object):

    server = None

    def start_server(self):
        handler = MyPageHandler
        self.server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 8000), handler)

        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
        server_thread.daemon = False
        server_thread.start()

    def stop_server(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
```

However occasionally when `stop_server` returns, the listening socket will still be opening. I have verified this by putting `os.system("netstat -ln | grep 8000")` at the end of `stop_server` and it often shows that the socket is still listening.

Is there a way to only return from `stop_server` once the socket has been closed?

Comment: Just try for once socket.close() before socket.shutdown() and see if something changes.

Comment: Is that the correct way to do this? I'm currently not accessing the socket directly, just using the `HTTPServer` class.

Comment: Maybe this provides you some hint http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746459/2382792

Comment: pss: No, it is not the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure but just try to add this self.server.close() before self.server.shutdown
Also can you please put the imports in your code and update your question, it helps to work quickly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this was solved by adding `server.server_close()` as @ρss suggested:

```
def stop_server(self):
    self.server.shutdown()
    self.server.server_close()
```