# How to run a thread more than once in python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I am trying to run a thread more than once and keep getting an error:

`RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`

I have tried reading up multithreading and implementing it in my code without any luck.

Here is the function I am threading:

```
def receive(q):
    host = ""
    port = 13000
    buf = 1024
    addr = (host,port)
    Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(addr)
    (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
    q.put(data)
```

Here is the code I want to run:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
r = threading.Thread(target=receive, args=(q,))

while True:
    r.start()
    if q.get() == "stop":
        print "Stopped"
        break
    print "Running program"
```

When the `stop` message gets sent, the program should break out of the while loop, but it does not run due to multithreading. The while loop should constantly print out `Running program`, until the `stop` message is sent.

The queue is used to receive the variable `data` from the `receive` function (which is the `stop`).

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745352/creating-a-multithreaded-server-using-socketserver-framework-in-python

Comment: You are constantly calling `r.start()`? Because if no message is received, your `q.get()` will return `None` (or maybe it is a blocking function, not sure?) and your code will try to start the thread again, even though the first instance is still running.

Comment: @Lawrence I am trying to overcome this with either stopping the thread at the end of the while loop, or creating another thread instance, which I am unsure on how to do.

Comment: The `threading` module has no attribute named `thread`, so you should be getting an `AttributeError` from the `threading.thread(target=receive, args=(q,))` statement.

Comment: @martineau Typo my bad, corrected with a captial `thread` with a captial T,  `Thread`. This should return the `RuntimeError`.

Comment: If a `Thread` is already running, it doesn't make sense to start it again. Perhaps you should also be creating a new instance of one inside the `while True` loop, and starting that -- although you could end up with a massive number of them. Probably better to put a `while` loop in `receive()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example (for python 2.7).

The program has two modes of operation:

- with no arguments it runs the receive loop
- with arguments it sends a datagram

Note how `r.start()` and `r.terminate()` are called outside of the while loop in `client`.
Also, `receive` has a `while True` loop.

```
import sys
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

UDP_ADDR = ("", 13000)

def send(m):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    sock.sendto(m, UDP_ADDR)

def receive(q):
    buf = 1024
    Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(UDP_ADDR)
    while True:
      (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
      q.put(data)

def client():
  q = Queue()
  r = Process(target = receive, args=(q,))
  r.start()

  print "client loop started"
  while True:
      m = q.get()
      print "got:", m
      if m == "stop":
          break
  print "loop ended"

  r.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = sys.argv
  if len(args) > 1:
    send(args[1])
  else:
    client()
```

Comment: This works fine. However, what if I were to receive multiple messages. So the first message that sends is `start` and then it loops to do something until `stop` is sent. I have modified your code slightly and added in what I have mentioned above: `while True:
    m = q.get()
    print "got:", m
    while m == "start":
     print "started"
     z = q.get()
     if z == "stop":
      return` @user5402

Comment: If you post it as another SO question I can answer it. This space is too small for a detailed answer.

Comment: You can view the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494890/handle-multiple-messages-with-queue-get) @user5402

Comment: This returns `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use` and does not work.. @user5402

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is once the thread is started, calling thread.start() again throws the error.

Using a try block would might work as a simple fix:

```html
while True:
    try:
      r.start()
    except Exception:  
#or except RunTimeError: 
      pass
    if q.get() == "stop":
        print "Stopped"
        break
    print "Running program"
```