# Handle multiple messages with Queue get()

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue, python-multithreading

Thanks to @user5402 for the previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487207/how-to-run-a-thread-more-than-once-in-python/27488251?noredirect=1#comment43421261_27488251).

I am trying to handle multiple messages that are queued up. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

UDP_ADDR = ("", 13000)

def send(m):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    sock.sendto(m, UDP_ADDR)

def receive(q):
    buf = 1024
    Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(UDP_ADDR)
    while True:
        (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
        q.put(data)
```

In the client function I want to handle multiple messages, that have knock on affects.

```
def client():
    q = Queue()
    r = Process(target = receive, args=(q,))
    r.start()

    print "client loop started"
    while True:
        m = q.get()
        print "got:", m
        while m == "start":
            print "started"
            z = q.get()
            if z == "stop":
                return
    print "loop ended"
    r.terminate()
```

So when `start` is sent, it then goes into a while loop that is infinitely printing `"started"`, and waiting for the `stop` message to come through. The above `client` code does not work.

Here is the code to start the function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv
    if len(args) > 1:
        send(args[1])
    else:
        client()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the client loop like this:

```
print "client loop started"
while True:
    m = q.get()
    print "waiting for start, got:", m
    if m == "start":
      while True:
        try:
          m = q.get(False)
        except:
          m = None
        print "waiting for stop, got:", m
        if m == "stop":
          break
```

Based on your comments, this would be a better approach:

```
import sys
import socket
import Queue as Q
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

UDP_ADDR = ("", 13000)

def send(m):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    sock.sendto(m, UDP_ADDR)

def receive(q):
    buf = 1024
    Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    Sock.bind(UDP_ADDR)
    while True:
      (data, addr) = Sock.recvfrom(buf)
      q.put(data)

def doit():
  # ... what the processing thread will do ...
  while True:
    print "sleeping..."
    time.sleep(3)

def client():
  q = Queue()
  r = Process(target = receive, args=(q,))
  r.start()

  print "client loop started"
  t = None   # the processing thread
  while True:
      m = q.get()
      if m == "start":
        if t:
          print "processing thread already started"
        else:
          t = Process(target = doit)
          t.start()
          print "processing thread started"
      elif m == "stop":
        if t:
          t.terminate()
          t = None
          print "processing thread stopped"
        else:
          print "processing thread not running"
      elif m == "quit":
        print "shutting down"
        if t:
          t.terminate()
          t = None  # play it safe
        break
      else:
        print "huh?"
  r.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = sys.argv
  if len(args) > 1:
    send(args[1])
  else:
    client()
```

Comment: This does not work, the `print "waiting for stop, got:", m` returns only one, when should be printing all the time until the `stop` is sent. The reason behind it printing all the time is because I will be inserting more code that requires the loop. @user5402

Comment: Answer updated - but you don't want to do it this way.

Comment: The program I am creating, it is constantly searching for signal strength using Bluetooth and bluez. I know it's bad practice, but it's the only way it will work. Thank you so much for your help! @user5402

Comment: This actually does not work, it returns a `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use` @user5402

Comment: Show me your complete program. You have another program/process listening to same port.

Comment: THe way you use the code above is 1) you start the server with `python program.py` and then you send commands with: 2) `python program.py some-command`. If you don't specify command line arguments in step 2 you will get the `Address already in use` error because you are starting two server programs.

Comment: OK so this is weird, I made sure there were no jobs running, and that didn't work. I restarted the machine and it worked again? The code is exactly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27488251/4241308) from your previous solution @user5402

Comment: That code works the same way. Start the server in one window and send commands in another. Use the command `netstat -an | grep 13000` to see if any process is listening on port 13000 (Linux or OSX.)