# python stop multithreaded echo server

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to create multithreaded echo server:

**echomain.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from echoserver import echoserver 
server = echoserver()

print server.isRunning()
print server.port()
server.start()
print "Main program continues..."\\This part is not displayed(((
```

**echoserver.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import socket

class connection(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sock, addr):
        self.sock = sock
        self.addr = addr
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run (self):
        while True:
            buffer = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if buffer == "disconnect\r\n":
                self.sock.send("bye")
                break
            elif buffer:
                self.sock.send(buffer)
        self.sock.close()

class echoserver(object):
    def __init__(self, port=12119):
        self.running = False
        self._port = port
        self._socket = None

    def isRunning(self):
        return self.running

    def port(self):
        return self._port

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port()))
        self._socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            conn, addr = self._socket.accept()
            connection(conn, addr).start()

    def stop(self):
        self._socket.close()
        print "Server is closed..."
```

Could somebody help me in how I can launch echoserver class as a thread so it run simultaneously with main program so I could stop it with stop() method in echomain.py part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746459/2382792

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to have your echoserver itself be a Thread as proposed by Reut Sharabani, but IMHO, you should also implement a correct stop() method, ensuring that all children have ended.

Here is my implementation of your script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import socket

class connection(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sock, addr, parent):
        self.sock = sock
        self.addr = addr
        self.parent = parent
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock.settimeout(None)
        self.closed = False # will be set to True on thread end
    def run (self):
        while not self.parent._stopped:
            buffer = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if buffer == "disconnected\r\n":
                self.sock.send("bye")
                break
            elif buffer:
                self.sock.send(buffer)
        self.sock.close()
        self.closed = True

class echoserver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port=12119):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = False
        self._port = port
        self._socket = None
        self._stopped = False
        self._conns = [] # list of active connections

    def isRunning(self):
        return self.running

    def port(self):
        return self._port

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port()))
        self._socket.listen(5)
        self._socket.settimeout(5) # use a timeout to respond to stop()
        while not self._stopped:
            try:
                conn, addr = self._socket.accept()
                c = connection(conn, addr, self)
                self._conns.append(c) # add child the the list
                c.start()
            except Exception as e:
                # print e # in debug
                pass
            self._conns = self.child_list() # remove closed child from list
        self._socket.close()
        print "Server is closing..."
        for connect in self._conns: # join active children
            connect.join()
        print "Server is closed"           

    def stop(self):
        self._stopped = True

    def child_list(self):
        l = []
        for conn in self._conns:
            if conn.closed:
                conn.join()
            else:
                l.append(conn)
        return l
```

Remarks :

- you simply use it that way :

  ```
  serv=echoserver()
  serv.start()
  ... # sleep of do anything you want
  serv.stop()
  ```
- if no connection is active when you call stop() all stops at the end of the accept timeout and you get :

  ```
  Server is closing...
  Server is closed
  ```
- if at least one connection is active when you call stop(), you get only `Server is closing...` at the end of the accept timeout. Then for each connection, it will end as soon as it receives a packet, and will be joined by echoserver. Then when all connection are over, you will get `Server is closed` and echoserver thread will terminate
- that means that in you main thread you have only to do

  ```
  serv.stop()
  serv.join()
  ```

to be sure that all other threads are correctly terminated, and that all sockets are closed

Answer (score 1):

Change your runner program to run the server as a thread:

**echomain.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from echoserver import echoserver
from threading import Thread
import time
server = echoserver()

print server.isRunning()
print server.port()
# server.start()
# run server in a different thread
serverThread = Thread(target=server.start)
serverThread.start()
print "main - server started"
# wait ten seconds before stopping
time.sleep(10)
server.stop()
print "main - server stopped"
print "Main program continues..."
```

This example simply stops the server after 10 seconds.