# Python TCP server stops responding

Tags: python, tcp, server

I have a simple TCP server set up in Python which posts data to another server when it gets a request and returns the data it receives from the client back to the client. After a while the server stops receiving any requests and quietly dies.

```
import SocketServer
import requests
import time

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print self.client_address
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()

        print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S "))

        params = {
            'hello': 'world'
        }

        requests.post('http://website.co.uk/test',data=params)

        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())
    def finish(self):
        print 'end request'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST,PORT = "192.168.2.211",343

    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST,PORT),TCPHandler)
    server.timeout = None
    server.serve_forever()
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows what might be causing the server to stop receiving requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe what "quietly dies" means. Also, what is the last line of code it runs before that?

Comment: This is a single process, single thread server. Maybe some connection is blocking it. Try `SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn` to make it process connections simultaneously. Also please try to debug it, for example with `strace`, to see what is hapenning exactly when it "dies".

Comment: By "quietly dies" I mean it doesn't return an error message, it just stops accepting requests. Also that's all of the code.

I'm starting to try using an asyncronous server, but right now I'm on a windows machine which doesn't seem to be helping, will be switching to a linux machine soon

Comment: This does not cope with multithreading: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745352/creating-a-multithreaded-server-using-socketserver-framework-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the link, will give that a read

Comment: Indeed most likely your server is stuck serving the pervious connection. Run it under `strace` to see where it stops. Or check with `netstat -p`