# How can I interrupt socket.accept() which is running in a different Thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I want to write a server that is accepting tcp connections but I do not want to block the main thread when I call `socket.accept()`, so I want to put the networking in a different thread. I have seen that there is no way to interrupt a thread in Python and now I am wondering how I could stop the `socket.accept()` call properly.

My desired solution would be something similar to Java, like:

```
class TcpServer:
    def waitForConnection():
        try:
            conn, addr = socket.accept()
        except ThreadInterrupt:
            # Close server ...
```

Unfortunately, this "ThreadInterrupt" does not exist. So, how can I achieve this behavior? Thanks in advance for each hint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745352/creating-a-multithreaded-server-using-socketserver-framework-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166547/raise-timeouterror-after-given-time-for-multiprocessing-connection-listener-acce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the socket to non-blocking operation, and wait with the good old `select` call for it to be ready for `accept` (when it becomes readable for
the first time). The added value is that you can listen for another file
descriptor, for example a pipe, this way you have a privileged communication
channel with your thread and you can exit the thread whenever you want:

```
import select
import socket
import os

class TcpServer:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.r_channel, self.w_channel = os.pipe() 
        self.socket = ...
    def waitForConnection(self):
        rfds, _, _ = select.select([self.socket.fileno(), self.r_channel],[],[])
        if self.r_channel in rfds:
            # close server
            ...
        self.socket.accept() # this won't block

# if you want to interrupt waitForConnection, from main thread:
os.write(tcp_server_object.w_channel, '!') # write something, just to wake up the select call
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. You should change the line `if self.r_channel in rfds:` to `if self.r_channel in rfds[0]:` because rfds is a triple of lists and we are searching in the first list for our r_channel. With this correction, it works for me.

Comment: Hi! It's weird because in my answer's code I get the 3 lists returned by `select` in 3 differents variables (rfds, _ and _). Did you copy the code exactly as it is or maybe you just did `rfds=select.select(...)` ?

Comment: For sure, you were right. I've changed the code and left out the underscores. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `settimeout` and signal to the thread via some variable (`CONDITION` in my example):

```
CONDITION = False
s.settimeout(1.0)
while True:
    try:
        if CONDITION: break
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        break

    except socket.timeout as e:
        pass
```

In another thread you have to set the `CONDITION` to True and you can test `CONDITION` after `while` block.